# Wanna Rewrite the url for a specific text

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project on some `.htaccess` task (and i am also new to `.htaccess`). my task is as follows

i am to redirect the url 
from

```
http://example.com/xxx-yyy-zzzz/?Facebook+CaracteresMx
```

to

```
http://example.com/xxx-yyy-zzzz/
```

and i am not able to remove the invalid query string `/?Facebook+CaracteresMx` from url.
Currently i am doing this with php (as getting the query string and then replace the text , then redirect) which slow down the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Facenook [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```